# How to use fnmatch to check pattern at specific position of string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fnmatch

I have a folder (call it `F`) with subfolders with names formatted as yyyy.doy (example 2020.001 for January first 2020). in each of the sub folders are file for multiple instruments. each file designates which instrument it is for in the 16th, 17th, and 18th character( a file fro instrument 1 would have a file as xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx001xxxxx). I am trying to create lists of file names and paths for each instrument using a python script.

If I was only looking in one of the subfolders I could use:

```
filelist=[]
for name in glob.glob('2020.001/*.001*'):
    print(name)
    filelist.append(name)
```

for the first instrument. I however would like to search all of the subfolders. From what I have found online I cannot use glob's recurse subfolder search to do this as my python version is 2.7. What I would like to do instead is use `fnmatch` in the format below (copied somewhat from another stack overflow page) but specifically searching those 16th, 17th and 18th characters.

```
filelist = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(folderpath)
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, [16:19]=='.001')]
```

the last part of this code `(files, [16:19]=='.001')` seems to fail on syntax. Can anyone help me reformat the code I have above or suggest a better way to create my lists? Keep in mind the lists will need to contain the full file path and name for each of the files but separated instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `fnmatch.filter` to do this, just a relatively basic Python `os.path` utility to split the file name split apart from the file's extension, and a conditional [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Here's what I mean.

```
import os

dirpath = './instrument_files'

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(dirpath):
    for f in (file for file in files 
                if os.path.splitext(file)[1].startswith('.001')):
        print(f)
```

Comment: I assume in the above answer "dirpath" refers to my F folder described in the initial question. "dirnames" refers to the subfolders and "files" would be the individual file names for each file. I see that "os.psth.splitext(file)[1] " would give me the extension to be compared to the string in startswith() but the 001,002,003,004,005, or 006 that identifies my instrument is not the extension of the file but characters 16,17, and 18 of a 24 character file name (24 includes the extension characters). can you explain any further how I could use this to check the specific characters i need?

Comment: mperrotta913: The `fnmatch` module doesn't support patterns that can do what you want — you can't specify character positions. I assumed the `.001` you have in your question indicated a file extension starting with the characters `001` (because of the leading `.`). Please clarify what the filenames look like and perhaps I can provide a different workaround for the `fnmatch` limitation.

Comment: thank you for your help, i realized I could read all of the files with their paths in all of the subfolders of dirpath into a list then filter the list by by specified characters. it added some time to the script but nothing compared to the time it takes to read variables from the file once they have been sorted.